# как создать приложение с интерфейсом которые будет считать простые квадратные уравнения?

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Iterface extends JFrame {
    private JButton button = new JButton("Найти значение");
    private JTextField inputA= new JTextField("", 5);
    private JTextField inputB = new JTextField("", 5);
    private JTextField inputC = new JTextField("", 5);
    private JLabel labelA = new JLabel("Задайте значение а: ");
    private JLabel labelB = new JLabel("Задайте значение b: ");
    private JLabel labelC= new JLabel("Задайте значение c: ");
    private JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox("Тест на робота", false);





    public Iterface (){
        super("Калькулятор простых квадратных уровнений");
        this.setBounds(100,100,600,200);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container container = this.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,2,5,5));
        container.add(labelA);
        container.add(inputA);
        container.add(labelB);
        container.add(inputB);
        container.add(labelC);
        container.add(inputC);
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        container.add(check);
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonEventListener ());
        container.add(button);

    }
    class ButtonEventListener implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            // a*x*2+b*x+c=0
            double a;
            double b;
            double c;
            double x1, x2;
            a = Double.parseDouble(inputA.getText());
            b = Double.parseDouble(inputB.getText());
            c = Double.parseDouble(inputC.getText());

            double Discriminant = b*b-4*(a*c); //формула Дискриминанта
            if (Discriminant == 0 ) { //если Дикср. = 0
                x1 = (-b) / (2 * a);
            }else if(Discriminant > 0 ){
                x1 = (-b+Math.sqrt(Discriminant))/(2*a);
                x2 = (-b-Math.sqrt(Discriminant))/(2*a);
            }else { //если Дикср. < 0
                System.out.println("Err");
            }
            String message = "";
            message += "Расчёт окончен!\n";
            message += "x1 = "+ inputA.getText() + "\n";
            message += "x2 = "+ inputB.getText() + "\n";
            message += ((check.isSelected())? "Вы Робот(": "Вы не робот!");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "Решение", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE );
        }

    }
}
```

это то что есть у меня, помогите сделать правильно

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на ваши строчки

```
    message += "x1 = "+ inputA.getText() + "\n";
    message += "x2 = "+ inputB.getText() + "\n";
```

Вы просто получаете введенный вами текст. Для чего тогда вы высчитывали х1 и х2?
Я убежден, что вина всему невнимательность, впредь внимательнее смотрите на свой код.
Исправьте на:

```
    message += "x1 = "+ x1 + "\n";
    message += "x2 = "+ x2 + "\n";
```

И не забудьте инициализировать эти переменные.

Comment: но ведь они же инициализированы в циклах if else? Или нет?

Comment: Инициализация может быть только при объявление, все что дальше это будет присвоением. Если вы оставите код как есть, не задав начальное значение иксам, то ошибка выскочит ещё до компиляции. Потому что у вас идёт попытка обратиться к переменной до ее инициализации. Подробнее читайте [ тут ] (https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/609-prisvaivanie-i-inicializacija-v-java) . Надеюсь я вам помог.

Comment: то есть я могу задать изначально иксам 0, и далее будет действовать на них цикл if else, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Да, все верно. Инициализация переменных - хорошая практика. В них не будет оставаться мусор при прошлых неудачных вызовах и прочее.